NPM always picks old version of Node-Gyp
I am working on building on Ionic project and I am newbie to Ionic too!
I would like to run npm install but it got failed with following error

Based on my observation and understanding, the node-gyp version running is 10.1.0. But project is always trying to use v3.8.0. Also, I understand that old version of node-gyp requires Python 2.x and the recent version requires Python 3.x.
The current node version installed in my machine is v20.15.0 and I want to have the updated version instead of downgrading the node version.
Where should I make changes in order to make the  node always pick the recent version installed?
Kindly help in fixing this.

If you call node-gyp -v you may be calling the global node-gyp, can you try with npx node-gyp --version or ./node_modules/.bin/node-gyp --version?

I tried using npx node-gyp --version and it shows the same updated version as 10.1.0

Can you share your package.json file?
